# Nested Pick of object properties

Tags: typescript, typescript2.1

I have some code that looks like this simplified example:

```
interface Foo {
    x: string;
    y: string;
}

interface Bar {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    foo: Foo
}

function printStuff(bar: Bar) {
    console.log(bar.a);
    console.log(bar.foo.x);
}
```

In my unit tests, I want want to call `printStuff` with the bare minimum parameters: `{a: 'someval', foo: {x: 1}}`. I don't want to construct an object with the complete parameter set for both `Foo` and `Bar`.

I realize I can write the parameter signature of `printStuff` as an anonymous interface, but then it's disconnected from any changes that occur to `Foo` and `Bar`. And it can get verbose if I use more properties from the parameter.

Can I instead use `Pick` to define the exact properties my function takes?

Comment: Check out `Partial`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to slice and dice this with `type` or `interface`.

Here's a granular approach that avoids anonymity and maintains relationships:

```
interface FooX { x: number; }
interface FooY { y: number; }

interface BarA { a: string; }
interface BarB { b: string; }

interface SlimBar extends BarA {
    foo: FooX;
}

interface Foo extends FooX, FooY {}

interface Bar extends BarA, BarB {
    foo: Foo;
}

function printStuff(bar: SlimBar) {
    console.log(bar.a);
    console.log(bar.foo.x);
}

const stuff = { a: 'someval', foo: { x: 1 } };
printStuff(stuff);
```

[Try it in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20interface%20FooX%20%7B%20x%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20FooY%20%7B%20y%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20BarA%20%7B%20a%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20BarB%20%7B%20b%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20SlimBar%20extends%20BarA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20FooX%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20Bar%20extends%20BarA%2C%20BarB%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20FooX%20%26%20FooY%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20printStuff(bar%3A%20SlimBar)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(bar.a)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(bar.foo.x)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20stuff%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20'someval'%2C%20foo%3A%20%7B%20x%3A%201%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20printStuff(stuff)%3B)

Or you can skip the extra types and cast as `any`:

```
function printStuff(bar: Bar) {
...
printStuff(stuff as any);
```